# undefined is not an object , can't access the Api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I have a problem when trying to use the API response in my components, I fetched the API stores the response correctly but when accessing the response object I get this error

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.employee_name')

here is my code :

```
export default  function TutorsScreen ({ navigation }) {

    let [response ,setResponse] =useState();

    useEffect(()  =>  {
        fetch("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((jsoon)=>setResponse(jsoon.data)) },[]);

return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          employee salary: {response.employee_salary} </Text>
        </View>
)
}
```

Comment: can you please console.log(jsoon.data) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`SOLUTION 1`**

You should set the initial state as `{}` empty object to `response` as:

```
let [response, setResponse] = useState({});
```

Because you are accessing it in JSX as:

```
{response.employee_salary}
```

The initial value is `undefined`. So your response is `undefined` and you can't access the property from `undefined`

**`SOLUTION 2`**

You can also use [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) as:

```
{response?.employee_salary}
```

**`SOLUTION 3`**

You can only render `Text` if `response` is truthy value i.e not undefined (in your case)

```
{
    response && (
        <Text
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
            style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}
        >
            employee salary: {response.employee_salary}
        </Text>
    )
}
```

Comment: Or don't render the `Text` until the response comes back

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is starting working after first render [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#what-are-effects-and-how-are-they-different-from-events)
so in first render this state is undefined. You can fix it in some ways

1.

```js
{ response?.employee_salary }
```

2. 

```js
{response?.employee_salary ?? 'Loading' }
```

or add loading state

```js
export default function App({ navigation }) {
  let [response, setResponse] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      fetch("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((jsoon) => {
        setResponse(jsoon.data);
      });
    }

    setLoading(true);
    await fetchData();
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">employee salary: {response?.employee_salary}</div>
  );
}
```